# Wordpress: Show post if it is in two specific categories

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter, categories, if-statement

I am trying to get the index-page of a Wordpress-blog show some very specific posts. As far as I understand i need to use a standard loop in order to make sticky posts work, so custom queries is out of the question. (Correct me if this is wrong.)

All posts are put in a main category (Eg. "Make-Up") In addition, posts that should show on the front page gets an additional category "Frontpage".

The current loop outputs all posts, regardless of category. And styles certain categories differently. An example would be the video-category which is only shown by getting an embed code from a custom field in the post.

```
 <?php elseif (in_category('20')) : ?>     
 <div class="post element grid_4">
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Embed', true) ?>
 </div>
```

I need to remove all posts not in the category "Frontpage" while still being able to control how posts are being shown.

Earlier i used a filter to control the main loop:

```
function exclude_category($query) {
if ( $query->is_home ) {
$query->set('cat', '20 27');
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

However this would cause my geomashup-plugin to break as it probably uses the same loop?

My current proposal for a solution would be to do something like this, plus functioning code:

```
 <?php elseif (the post is in BOTH category 20 and 27)) : ?>     
 <div class="post element grid_4">
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Embed', true) ?>
 </div>

 <?php else : ?>     
 <div style: display: none;></div>
```

However i am unsure about how make a condition demanding the post to be in two categories, and i realise this is a terribly dirty fix.

Any tips or pointers as to how i could solve this would be greatly appreciated :)

Front page can be seen here: http://parfymelle.brandbase.no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering i solved it by including the geotagged posts-category (the shop locations) in the filter for the main loop, and then using a php if in the index.php to hide posts from that category. Dirty, but works, i guess.